# Can someone tell what are primitive translation vectors for BCC lattice?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, lattice-model

I referred internet and two very renowned books ( Puri-Babbar and SO PILLAI ).
COULDN'T find any primitive translation vector explanation for BCC or FCC.

Eventually when I moved on to Reciprocal Lattices for BCC lattice. I saw a rhombohedron being used to explain the BCC translation vector. Three BCC connected together to give out vectors. [ In a PDF from some presentation in UC BERKELEY ].

But from what I know translation vector make up the cell but I don't think thr translation vectors being used here can make up anything apart from atom in the centre of BCC.
There are no translation vector for atoms at corner.

I am confused what's going on.

**I can't upload the screenshot image here. It's saying something went wrong.**

**I can attach the URL to PDF though. images I am referring to are at page 5-6**

[PDF LINK](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.cchem.berkeley.edu/pdygrp/253a/253A-s13_02.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjnupm0qJDoAhXj7XMBHdYJAQgQFjAVegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0eHKXHOL3pDX5FO6IN5vGo)

---

Edit:

Page-5

[image: Page-5]

Page-6
[image: Page-6]

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the text. Consider checking if they are the right ones.

Comment: @JohanLiebert  thank you ! absolutely right. I couldn't upload them

Comment: Are you still having the problem?

Comment: @JohanLiebert uploading image ? Yes. Regarding question no but I needed a bit confirmation on something that I added in a comment below. Rest is fine back to study. I scored 73 in your nerd test.

Comment: Yes regarding the image. Are you still facing the problem or is it gone?

Comment: @JohanLiebert still can't upload. Guess you gotta have more than specific amount of points to upload. Rest is fine

Comment: @Rob I am using android. App hasn't been updated since 30 June 2017. Ancient functionality.

Comment: user10339666, The [App is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328697/android-app-doesnt-explain-why-image-upload-fails?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1072879_328697) and [won't be updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/282094), use Chrome or Firefox for Android.

Comment: @Rob is there any other third party app that uses the API of this app but works fluidly sorry for the off topic question.

Comment: This [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202732/282094) and it's link: https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/android provides a number of APPs; not sure if there's a direct replacement in there somewhere. This looks like one solution: https://stackapps.com/q/3178/58236 it's read-only, clicking opens a web browser and write access is gained that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no unique base of primitive vectors. What is required is that all points of the lattice can be reached by a linear combination of them, with integer coeficients. One good choice is to take the origin in a corner of the cube. Two vectors are arests of the cube, and so orthogonal. The third one goes until the point in the center of the cube.

Comment: Thank you very much.That answers for why we considered only face atoms in FCC. One little favor I want is to confirm that taking three BCC for giving BCC translation vector was just for mathematical ease to get the vectors or there is some different underlying thing

Comment: Another good choice is to take three vectors to the closest lattice points (to three cube centers).

Comment: And is there some different way to get translation vector for BCC